# Ошибка при добавлении фонового изображения

Tags: c#, wpf

Необработанное исключение типа "`System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException`" в `PresentationFramework.dll`

Дополнительные сведения: "Предоставление значения для "`System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension`" вызвало исключение.": номер строки "6" и позиция в строке "10".

При добавлении фонового изображения у любого элемента вылазит эта ошибка. Все пути есть, все правильно, даже в конструкторе все правильно. Подскажите, чем это может быть вызвано?
6 строка - как раз строка, где добавляется фоновое изображение (`XAML`).

Разметка самая обычная:

```
<Window x:Class="Project.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStyle="None">
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Background.png"/>
</Window.Background>

<Grid Height="300" Width="500" Margin="6,28,6,6" Background="White">
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Пробовал и через ресурсы, и через обычные пути (`ImageSource="img/Background.png"`).

Comment: Вы приведите саму разметку, а то на кофейной гуще вряд ли кто-то гадать будет

Comment: `siteoforigin` неправильно, это же placeholder. Почитайте документацию по поводу того, что именно вам нужно. Скорее всего, `application`.

Comment: У меня так конструктор определил. Странно. Спасибо

Comment: Заменил на `application`, все равно не работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> У кого выскакивает подобное исключение смотрите в свойствах изображения "Действие при построении" : Resource

См. http://www.cyberforum.ru/post6254212.html